# Stop thread on button click

Tags: java, android, multithreading, button

I have a new thread in my android application which counts up to 60 (in seconds) and then refreshes the view. But on this view there is a back button. So when I hit the back button, the view changes to the view it should, but the running extra thread counts on. How can I stop this thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a `Handler` and `Runnable`. Use something like that :

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runable = new Runnable({
   @Override
   public void run(){
        // count
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
   }
});
```

and in your `onClick();` you can do `handler.removeCallbacks(runable);`

Comment: Ok, but how do I start this runnable?

Comment: Just call `handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);`.

Comment: Handler class belong on which package.?